# Clean OS X install, keeping Time Machine history?

Tags: time-machine, install, history

I need to wipe and rebuild my Macbook Pro Retina's hard drive (OS X Yosemite, if it matters) and am planning on using Setup Assistant to restore all my data from my Time Machine backup. Question: once I do this, will my existing Time Machine history be preserved, so that I can, say, go and find a file's version as of two months ago? Or, is there a way of accessing my old Time Machine data through the Time Machine interface (so I don't have to burrow through all the hidden Time Machine files)?

(This question was previously asked as ["Clean Lion install, keeping Time Machine history?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49149/clean-lion-install-keeping-time-machine-history), but the fundamental question of Time Machine History was never answered.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I tried it, and indeed the Time Machine history is preserved (at least with OS X Yosemite). I did the following:

- Erased the hard drive
- Installed Yosemite
- Restored from my Time Machine backup drive

After all this was done, and with the backup drive connected, I entered Time Machine on my Documents folder, and there was the history.

Good work, Apple!

Edit: I finally had to buy a new MacBook Pro, and used Setup Assistant again to transfer all my files from my old MacBook's Time Machine archive. It worked well, and when I was done I booted from my new MacBook everything was there.

Interestingly, when I re-enabled Time Machine on my new MacBook, still attached to my old MacBook's Time Machine disk, I got the following dialog (actually with different disk names):

[image: Inherit Time Machine dialog]

Sure enough, after I chose "Inherit Backup History" my new Mac was using the old Time Machine backup disk, history in all. Way, way cool.